How to List All Combinations of Values from Two Semicolon-Separated Columns in Excel/Sheets?
This might be a very beginner's question, but after searching unsuccessfully, I decided to ask for help, although I have the feeling that the answer is just within reach.
I'm working on a glossary in Excel/Sheets, where each row contains a list of related terms in two columns: Column A (English terms) and Column B (Spanish terms). Semicolons separate the terms in each column. For example:



English
Spanish




a; b
C; D


e
F; G


h; i
J



I need to output all possible combinations (like a Cartesian product) of the terms from Column A and Column B within the same row in separate rows. The result for the above example should be like this:



English
Spanish




a
C


a
D


b
C


b
D


e
F


e
G


h
J


i
J



Can you help me with a formula or any other method to achieve that in Excel?
I tried SPLIT function, for example, which divides text around a specified character or string, and puts each fragment into a separate cell in the row, but that is not what I'm actually looking for, and would be extremely tedious to manually rearrange for hundreds or thousands of values.

It's either Excel or Google-sheets, both though very similar, might have slight differences, that will make or break a function in either. Please choose one and [edit] your tags accordingly.

@Excellor I suggested that the OP should decide between Excel or Googlesheets - seems to have disappeared...

@SolarMike was it perhaps in Staging Ground?

This is a link where you can see several workarounds of the problem. You have to apply something like them to all rows of data in your table.

@Blackcat the question mentions Cartesian product but it is not really about that. This kind of thing can nowadays be done with plain vanilla formulas without resorting to scripting.

@double I not really know which question is not really about that. What I commented that this question's one row expanded the data to columns is similar to the link a attached.

@Blackcat yeah, the outputs look similar, but I don't think that any of the answers at the linked question help solve this one.

In Google Sheets:
=let( 
  get_, lambda(a, filter(a, len(A2:A), len(B2:B))), 
  split_, lambda(a, split(a, "; ", false)), 
  pairs, map(get_(A2:A), get_(B2:B), lambda(en, es, 
    torow(sort(split_(en) & "→" & tocol(split_(es)))) 
  )), 
  sort(split(tocol(pairs, 1), "→")) 
)


See
let(),
lambda(),
filter(),
split(),
map(),
torow(),
tocol()
and
sort().

Thank you very much, @doubleunary! I can't say I understood that formula – I'm not an Excel/Sheets advanced user – but it worked liked a charm.

With Microsoft 365:
REDUCE is used to accumulate combined rows, DROP initial value when not needed later.
=LET(
    last_data_cell, B50000,
    data, A1:INDEX(B1:last_data_cell, COUNTA(B1:last_data_cell)),
    comb_one, LAMBDA(acc, row,
        LET(
            lang2rows, TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(data, row, 2), , ";"),
            VSTACK(
                acc,
                DROP(
                    REDUCE(
                        "Append combinations for single row",
                        TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(data, row, 1), ";"),
                        LAMBDA(acc, _l1,
                            VSTACK(acc, HSTACK(EXPAND(_l1, ROWS(lang2rows), , _l1), lang2rows))
                        )
                    ),
                    1
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    TRIM(REDUCE(TAKE(data, 1), SEQUENCE(ROWS(data) - 1, , 2), comb_one))
)



In Excel using Office 365 this could be an approach:
=LET(SPLIT,LAMBDA(range,_c1,_c2,
      LET(
          dlm,"; ",
          _i1,INDEX(range,,_c1),
          t,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(dlm&_i1,dlm,SEQUENCE(,MAX(1+LEN(_i1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(_i1,";",""))))),dlm),
          SORTBY(
                 HSTACK(                  
                        TOCOL(t,2),                  
                        TOCOL(IF(LEN(t),INDEX(range,,_c2)),2)),
                 (-1*(_c1>_c2))*{1,2}))),
SPLIT(SPLIT(A2:B4,1,2),2,1))

You could also create a named range  lambda called SPLIT which uses arguments range (both columns), _c1 the column index of the range to split, _c2 the column index of the other column:
LAMBDA(range,_c1,_c2,LET(dlm,"; ",_i1,INDEX(range,,_c1),t,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(dlm&_i1,dlm,SEQUENCE(,MAX(1+LEN(_i1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(_i1,";",""))))),dlm),
SORTBY(HSTACK(TOCOL(t,2),TOCOL(IF(LEN(t),INDEX(range,,_c2)),2)),(-1*(_c1>_c2))*{1,2})))

And then you can simply use: =SPLIT(SPLIT(A2:B4,1,2),2,1)
Or kinda same logic as posted Google Sheets solution:
=LET(a,A2:A4,b,B2:B4,REDUCE(A1:B1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(TOCOL("|"&TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(a,y),,"; ")&"|"&TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(b,y),"; ")),"|",{1,2}),"|")))))
